# Как организовать ввод данных в одной строке и определить их тип?

Tags: python, input

На вход принимается либо дата в формате "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ" либо текстом в формате "первое января двадцатьпервогогода". Суть программы - конвертация формата даты в зависимости от формата ввода.
К примеру:

- **input** - 15.03.2004
- **output** - пятнадцатое марта дветысячичетвёртогогода

  либо
- **input** - пятнадцатое марта дветысячичетвёртогогода
- **output** - 15.03.2004

Вопрос: как организовать ввод с определением формата (число это или строка) и разделением по дню, месяцу и году. Спасибо

//////////////////////////////////////

**я пришёл к тому, что проще всего проверить третий символ ввода, если он является точкой:**

```
date = input()
if date[2]=='.':
    l = list(map(int, date.split('.')))
    d = l[0]
    m = l[1]
    y = l[2]
else:
    l = list(map(str, date.split()))
    d = l[0]
    m = l[1]
    y = l[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

создай массив для тех данных, которые ты хочешь принимать и обрабатывать

```
day_dict = {
   1: 'первое',
   2: 'второе',
   ...
   31: 'тридцать первое',
}
month_dict = {
  1: 'января',
  2: 'февраля',
 ...
}
```

с годами посложней нужно разбить число на составляющие

```
year_thousands = {
   1: 'одна',
   2: 'две',
...
}
year_hundred = {
    100: 'сто',
    200: 'двести',
...
    900: 'девятьсот'
}
year_decades = {
    20: 'двадцать',
    30: 'тридцать'
    90: 'девяносто'
}
```

в единицы так же проще закинуть все значения до 19

```
year_numbers = {
    1: 'первого',
    ...
    19: 'девятнадцатого'
}
```

затем функции для преобразования

```
def date_to_str(yearday, month, year):
   собирай строку из предыдущих заоплненных массивов
   return получившийся результат

def str_date(date_str):
   разбирай строку на слова и найди месяц
   он будет либо вторым либо третим словом, 
   т.е. проверяй второй и третье слово на наличие в масиве месяцов 
   потом найди день, месяц и сохрани их в переменные day, month
   оставшиеся слова относятся к году. год придется собирать по частям
   соответственно у года 
   если второе слово будет либо тысячи либо тысяча, тогда первое число - номер тысячелетия(его находишь опять по  словарю `year_thousands`), прибаляешь значение year += число * 1000
   остальные слова банально находишь на на личие в словарях
   `year_hundreds`, `year_decades`, `year_numbers` и прибавляешь соответственно year += число * 100 / 10 / 1 в зависимости от того, в каком словаре нашлось
   затем из составляющих day, month, year составляешь дату в нужном тебе формате
   return получившийся результат
```

для того, что бы определить ввели дату или строку используй `try... except...`

```
from datetime import datetime

input_value = input()
try:
    date_value = datetime.strptime(value, '%d.%m.%Y')
    result_message = date_to_str(day = date_value.day, month = date_value.month, year=date_value.year)
except ValueError:
    result_message = str_to_date(date_str=input_value)

print(result_message)
```

Comment: я написал функции для перевода из даты из формата "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ" в формат "день месяц год" , но не могу понять (извините, даже после вашего ответа), как мне проверить, вводится ли дата в формате "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ" или в формате "день месяц год". на основе проверки я буду вызывать нужные для преобразования функции.

Comment: внизу ответа есть блок `try...except...` в котором мы пытаемся преобразовать введенные пользователем данные в дату, если преобразовывается нормально, то значит формат ДД.ММ.ГГГГ иначе вызывается исключение. И мы в блоке исключения понимаем, что была введена строка с датой